# C# winforms Mono mkbundle - 'as' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: c#, winforms, mono, mkbundle

I've been attempting to get my C# winforms application to run on Linux and Mac using Mono. The program runs and works fine using:

```
mono <path-to-exe>
```

However, I would like to package Mono with the program, so I've been using the mkbundle command. My exact input is this:

```
mkbundle --deps -o <project-name> <path-to-exe> <path-to-3rd-party-dll>
```

Mono seems to embed all dlls fine (with the 3rd party one last), but then outputs this error:

```
AS = as (default)
as -o temp.o temp.s
'as' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
ERROR: [Fail] 1
```

Any clue as to what the problem is?